# Should we create one Azure CosmosDB per web application or multiple ones?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I setup a web app with Azure cosmos db. I came across that we have a limit on the number of containers per DB. Now it is 25 containers when we have shared throughput.
What is the best practice here:

1. Creating multiple databases per application although the app is not microservices.
2. User serverless cosmos db
3. Put the throughput on the container level.

please advise.

Comment: Can you give more details? Why do you have 25 containers? Is it a container per tenant?

Comment: I have a container for each entity like `Organizations` and `Users`... So the containers number reaches this limit easily.

Comment: How you organize your containers is really up to you. But just remember that a container is not the same thing as a relational database table. I suggest reading a few tutorials around document databases to learn more about how to organize data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a container for each entity like Organizations and Users... So the containers number reaches this limit easily.

I think you need to rethink you design. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/account-databases-containers-items#azure-cosmos-containers):

> A container is a schema-agnostic container of items. Items in a container can have arbitrary schemas. For example, an item that represents a person and an item that represents an automobile can be placed in the same container. By default, all items that you add to a container are automatically indexed without requiring explicit index or schema management. You can customize the indexing behavior by configuring the indexing policy on a container.

Do not fall into the trap of trying to map a relational database schema to the resource model of Cosmos DB. Do not think of a container as a table. Have you read the [modeling guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data) already?

Comment: Thanks Peter, so in your opinion, we shouldn't reach this limit at all?. In case we reach it. What is the correct approach? Create a new DB or think about putting the throughput on the container level.

Comment: Also in case, we have multi-tenancy app. Is there a known pattern for data modeling?.